# What is ex(n, H) (Turan Number)?

Tags: graph-theory

I am struggling with understanding what exactly does $ex(n, K_{n,n})$ represent? It's defined as the turan number, but what exactly does this mean visually in terms of graphs? The formal definition that I have is $ex(n, K_{n,m}) = \max\{|E(G)|\cdot |V(G)| = n, K_{n,m} \text{ is not an induced subgraph of G}\}$. I understand the definition, but if I were given values of let's say $n = 50$ and $K_{n,m} = K_{3,5}$, how would I get to the $ex(50, K_{3,5})$?

Also, how is the Turan number related to the Turan graph? Would also be grateful if anyone could direct me to any resources where I can read more about that- books or videos?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually easy to find any particular value $\mathrm{ex}(n,H)$. In your example, if we're looking for $\mathrm{ex}(50,K_{3,5})$, we are looking for a $50$-vertex graph with no $K_{3,5}$ subgraphs in it, and we want it to have as many edges as possible.

We can prove some *lower* bounds on this number without too much effort. For example, the graph $K_{2,48}$ has no copies of $K_{3,5}$ in it; since $K_{2,48}$ has $96$ edges, we know $\mathrm{ex}(50,K_{3,5}) \ge 96$. Of course, proving better lower bounds requires creativity.

Proving any kind of upper bound is tricky. Here's one approach that does not use sophisticated tools. Suppose we have a $50$-vertex graph $G$ with three vertices $u,v,w$ of degree at least $35$. There are at most $14$ vertices in the rest of the graph not adjacent to $u$, at most $14$ not adjacent to $v$, and at most $14$ not adjacent to $w$; delete them all, and we are still left with $u,v,w$ and $5$ more vertices, which must form a $K_{3,5}$. So if $G$ does *not* have a $K_{3,5}$, it can have at most $2$ vertices with degree $35$ or more. This gives us a degree sum of at most $2 \cdot 49 + 48 \cdot 34 = 1730$, for at most $865$ edges; we have shown that $\mathrm{ex}(50,K_{3,5}) \le 865$.

Of course, if all we can say is that $96 \le \mathrm{ex}(50,K_{3,5}) \le 865$, that's not saying much. Lots of work has been done to get better bounds (in general, not specifically for this example). For example, the Kővári–Sós–Turán theorem gives a bound of $O(n^{2-1/\min\{s,t\}})$ on $\mathrm{ex}(n,K_{s,t})$; I am not sure what the constant is, so I'm not sure what their bound gives when $n=50$.

---

The relationship between the Turán numbers and the Turán graph is that the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $T(n,r)$ turns out to be the $n$-vertex graph with the most edges that does not contain a $K_{r+1}$. So if $e(T(n,r))$ is the number of edges in the Turán graph, then $\mathrm{ex}(n,K_{r+1}) = e(T(n,r))$. This is approximately $(1 - \frac1r)\binom n2$.